# Possible to filter audit log by recently changed field

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

Morning-
I have an entity with auditing enabled, and would like to be able to search that entity based on whether or not a field value has been changed in the past week.

In the audit summary view in Dynamics online, it does not appear that I can achieve that.  Is there any other way I can get the functionality short of coding?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this exactly, but you have a number of options to approximate this:

1) Only turn on auditing for that particular field

2) Filter for Update Event and you can filter down to that particular entity

3) Set up a workflow that runs on the update of that field only - then look for those records where that workflow is a related record